# Appending a List of Elements to a List<List<T>>

Tags: c#, list

```
// I have a first list of ElementIds
List<ElementId> list1

// I appended it to a higher list as below
List<List<ElementId>> ElementIds = new List<List<ElementId>>();
ElementIds.Append(list1);

// Got another list
List<ElementId> list2

// When I tried to append the second list to the higher list
ElementIds.Append(list2);

// Both the 1st and the 2nd in the higher list "ElementIds" are getting updated with the list2.
```

I want the list2 to be appended to the higher list "ElementIds" without affecting the first one appended to the higher list "ElementIds".`

Comment: Appending `list2` would not affect `list1` unless you do something weird in retrieving those lists (maybe you should show that).

Comment: Edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If `ElementID` is a reference type, this might explain some of the behavior you are seeing.  We can advise you more precisely if you give us a better code sample.

Comment: Maybe the "words" your are looking for are that you want to "clone" a list. If that's the case, there is "deep" cloning and "shallow" cloning.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, you shouldn't be getting this problem. This would only occur when appending the same list instance multiple times.

You could try creating a new list from the existing one before appending:

```
ElementIds.Append(new List<ElementId>(list2));
```

Without more context, it's hard to find the exact solution to the problem.

Comment: `List<T>` doesn't have an `Append` method [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-8.0#methods). You're therefore using LINQ's `Append` method, which doesn't change the contents of `ElementIds`. If you `foreach` over the resulting `IEnumerable<List<ElementId>>`, you'll see your appended item, but you won't find it in `ElementIds`. Because of this, `ElementIds.Append(new List<ElementId>(list2));` does nothing because you're discarding the result. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=net-8.0).